# How did the objective-c object reference count is set to -1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I was using XCode's zombie profiling problem of message sended to dealloced object . and the profilie log this

[image]

you can see that in #49, the reference delta is -1 ,but the RefCt is set from 2 to -1 suddenly ,

And in #50 , another delta is -1 ,but the RefCt is change from -1 to 0.

How to understand these two steps of changes ?

Comment: I suspect that's just an incorrect number.  Line 10 should have a ref count of 4 but it reported 0.  Line 49 should probably have a ref count of 1, but it reports -1 instead.  Probably just ignore those.  On line 50, the final release is issued, deallocating the object.  But then it appears there was another call to isAnimating after that, which presumably calls its layer, and would be the crash.  So you basically need to figure out where a retain call was missing, from that above list, which caused the CALayer to be deallocated early.

Comment: The usual process here is to "pair" each retain/release that looks correct, meaning those are not the source of the problem.  For example, CALayer setFrame looks like it retains the layer twice and releases it twice -- no problem.  So those can be paired off and ignored.  The two lines with bogus ref count values also look to be a pair -- those would not be the problem either.  Once you get down to the ones that are left, the problem would be in those areas, most likely.